# How do I display units when doing snmpwalk?

Tags: net-snmp, mib, oid, snmpwalk

This is a part of my MIB :

```
callSuccessRate OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX Integer32
    UNITS        "%"
    MAX-ACCESS read-write
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Success rate of call"
    DEFVAL { 0 }
    ::= { call 1 }
```

When I run `snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost callSuccessRate` I get :

```
MY-MIB::callSuccessRate = INTEGER: 33
```

How can I display the units at the end of my integer ?

I tried using **"DISPLAY-HINT"** :

```
callSuccessRate OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX Integer32
    DISPLAY-HINT        "%"
    MAX-ACCESS read-write
    STATUS current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Success rate of call"
    DEFVAL { 0 }
    ::= { call 1 }
```

But my output remains the same :

```
MY-MIB::callSuccessRate = INTEGER: 33
```